# Two successive preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use two `preg_match` in order to get two specific values from an `html` source code.

```
<?php

    $url = "http://www.example.com";
    $userAgent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10000000);  
    $html  = curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match('~<span class="first">(.*)<\/span>~msU',$html,$matching_data);
    preg_match('~<span class="second">(.*)<\/span>~msU',$html,$matching_data2);
    print_r($matching_data);
    print_r($matching_data2);   
?>
```

Taking in consideration that the `$html` var contains the following sequence:

```
<title>foobar title</title>
<body>
<div class="second">Not this one</span>
<div>
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">this one<span>
</div>
</body>
```

If I run my `php` code, the first `print_r` returns the right value: `<span class="first">First</span>`. But the second `print_r`, instead of returning `<span class="second">this one<span>` it returns `<div class="second">Not this one</span>`.

So I guess that the `preg_match` function begins the treatment from the beginning instead of the last `preg_match` call.

How can I make the second (third, fourth, etc.) call of `preg_match` runs at the last call?

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: You could use preg_match_all.

Comment: How can I use the preg_match_all in my case? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sequential calls to `preg_match`, continuing the search where you last left off, use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

As for the larger problem though, regular expressions are generally not suitable for parsing HTML.  You should be using some sort of DOM parser to do this work for you, and that's if you even need to do the work on the server side.  This sort of thing can be done extremely simply (and naturally) on the client side using JavaScript -- you would just have to pass back the relevant values back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the offset capture and offset arguments in the preg_match function ([php:preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php))

`int preg_match ( string $pattern, string $subject [, array &$matches`**`[, int $flags [, int $offset]]] )`**

try this:

```
<?php

...

preg_match('~<span class="first">(.*)<\/span>~msU',$html,$matching_data,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
preg_match('~<span class="second">(.*)<\/span>~msU',$html,$matching_data2,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $matching_data[0][1]+strlen($matching_data[0][0]));
print_r($matching_data);
print_r($matching_data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that HTML the code you need to work with? It's not valid HTML. You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) as @igorw suggested:

```
preg_match_all('~<(span|div) class="(first|second)">(.*)<\/?span>~msU', $html,$matching_data);
echo '<xmp>'; print_r($matching_data[0]);
```

But if the HTML was valid:

```
<title>foobar title</title>
<body>
<span class="second">Not this one</span>
<div>
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">this one</span>
</div>
</body>

preg_match_all('~<span class="(first|second)">(.*)<\/span>~msU', $html, $matching_data);
echo '<xmp>'; print_r($matching_data[0]);
```